# Why didn't 'npm install canvas' create a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, webpack

I am new to node packages. I attempted to install canvas to my project using:

```
npm install canvas
```

Before I could get this to work I needed to install gtk and cairo following the instructions here: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/619

After following the above instructions npm install canvas generated no errors and here is the full output (I don't see any errors):

```
canvas@1.6.5 install 
C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas>if not
defined npm_config_node_gyp (node
"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )  Building the projects in this
solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m"
switch.   Canvas.cc   CanvasGradient.cc   CanvasPattern.cc  
CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc ..\src\CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc(801):
warning C4458: declaration of 'constructor' hides class member
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
c:\users\user\desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\src\CanvasRenderingContext2d.h(72):
note: see declaration of 'Context2d::constructor' (compiling source
file ..\src\CanvasRenderingContext2d.cc) ..\src\Canvas.cc(154):
warning C4457: declaration of 'data' hides function parameter
[C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
..\src\Canvas.cc(150): note: see declaration of 'data'   color.cc  
Image.cc   ImageData.cc   init.cc   win_delay_load_hook.cc
     Creating library C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.lib
and object
C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.exp
Generating code   Finished generating code   canvas.vcxproj ->
C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\\canvas.node
canvas.vcxproj ->
C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.pdb
(Full PDB)   Copying C:/GTK/bin/libcairo-2.dll to
C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\\libcairo-2.dll
          1 file(s) copied.   Copying C:/GTK/bin/libfontconfig-1.dll to
C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\\libfontconfig-1.dll
          1 file(s) copied.   Copying C:/GTK/bin/libexpat-1.dll to C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\\libexpat-1.dll
          1 file(s) copied.   Copying C:/GTK/bin/libfreetype-6.dll to C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\\libfreetype-6.dll
          1 file(s) copied.   Copying C:/GTK/bin/libpng14-14.dll to C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\\libpng14-14.dll
          1 file(s) copied.   Copying C:/GTK/bin/zlib1.dll to C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\\zlib1.dll
          1 file(s) copied.   win_delay_load_hook.cc   Generating code   Finished generating code   canvas-postbuild.vcxproj ->
C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\\canvas-postbuild.node
canvas-postbuild.vcxproj ->
C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas-postbuild.pdb
(Full PDB) myproject@0.1.15 C:\Users\user\Desktop\latest\myproject `--
canvas@1.6.5
```

I don't see any errors however when I perform npm start I see:

```
ERROR in ./~/canvas/lib/bindings.js Module not found: Error: Can't
resolve '../build/Release/canvas' in     
'C:\Users\me\myapp\node_modules\canvas\lib' @
./~/canvas/lib/bindings.js 3:17-51 @ ./~/canvas/lib/canvas.js @
./app/app.js @ ./app/components/base/base.spec.js
```

I look in the bindings.js file and the only code is:

```
module.exports = require('../build/Release/canvas');
```

I navigate to the `../build/Release/canvas` folder and find 5 files named canvas with different extensions:

```
canvas.exp
canvas.lib
canvas.map
canvas.node
canvas.pdb
```

However there is no canvas.js or other file. None of the files in the 'Release' folder are even javascript. What did I do wrong? What do I need to do right?

Comment: It'll be reading the `canvas.node` file. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Comment: So then is the problem to do with how the canvas.node file was compiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't generate a `.js` file because it uses a `.node` file, which is the extension used for native Node Addons, and Node.js will load it just fine.

From [Node.js - File Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules):

> If the exact filename is not found, then Node.js will attempt to load the required filename with the added extensions: `.js`, `.json`, and finally `.node`.

Node is perfectly happy with a `.node` file, so you can just import it without explicitly adding the extension.

Webpack on the other hand does not look for `.node` by default. As show in [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions), the default is:

```
extensions: [".js", ".json"]
```

You can change that in your webpack config to:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: [".js", ".json", "node"]
}
```

As [`.node` files are loaded differently by Node](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/addons.html#addons_loading_addons_using_require), you'll probably also need [`node-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/node-loader) to make it work in webpack.

Note: Native Node Addons won't work in the browser and for them to work with webpack you'll likely need to set [`target: 'node'`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) and you might also need to tell webpack to defer the `require` to run-time by defining it as an [external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).